# How to update Gradle project locked dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-dependencies

I'm updating AWS Java SDK version using IntellJ, tried everything but both compileClasspath & runtimeClasspath dependency doesn't change at all.

Here is the Project https://github.com/Netflix/conductor

main build.gradle file
https://github.com/Netflix/conductor/blob/main/build.gradle

The dependency I'm trying to update is in here
https://github.com/Netflix/conductor/blob/main/awssqs-event-queue/build.gradle

Updated to a different version

[image][image]

Here I tried buildDependency option

[image]

Also tried reload Gradle project
[image]

Here I expect the SDK version to be changed but did not.

[image]

Comment: Can you add content of build.gradle? Or at least sections like: dependencies, dependencyManagement? It may be that the version is forced via another library so you can also try generating dependency tree to see where the current library version comes from.

Comment: Hi @makozaki, I've added the build.gradle link, its an open source project. You are right it's used in another place, but the version is referenced in a common ext context, I'm new to Java how do you generating dependency tree ?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html
I'll look into dependencies and get back to you.

Comment: Have you run **Reload** action after a change? Also, compare with what you have when showing the project's Gradle dependencies tree from the command line: `./gradlew -q conductor-awssqs-event-queue:dependencies`.

Comment: Based on the command line Gradle report I checked - it looks like Gradle itself prefers `1.11.86` version: `+--- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:1.11.103 -> 1.11.86` You should check the rules for Gradel in this project. It looks like the verison is locked in `dependencies.lock` file.

Comment: Thx @Andrey just realised there is .lock file in each folder, can I change the version in the lock file? I new to Gradle, I through it suppose to be auto generated.

Comment: Looking at lock files it looks like a 3rd party plugin produces these files. By quick search I found this: [gradle-dependency-lock-plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-dependency-lock-plugin/wiki/Usage) I'd advise to contact other project members to discuss how the dependencies are managed and then update the lock files accordingly.